# Can you use the PayPal Php SDK any more for direct credit card payments?

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

I have not been able to get a clear answer on this. I have fully set up the PayPal SDK REST API in Php and while it works perfectly fine in sandbox, live payments are returning a 401 error, which from log-digging turns out to be an UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT error. My hunch is that they no longer support direct credit card payments via anything except Braintree as a lot has seemed to indicate that, but nowhere has stated it directly.

And ultimately, it seems extremely unusual that it would work perfectly with test credit cards in sandbox, but fail on live. Everything says enabled for live in the dev account, the Paypal account is linked to a bank account (although only just today, so perhaps that is the issue--it needs to be bank verified?).

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal SDK REST API for direct credit card payments is deprecated.